# Python 3.x: function to determine missing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'var1': ['pero03930', 'pero03930', ' '],
        'var2': ['121324', '232434', ' '],
        'var3': [343, 937, 989],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])

print(df)
```

I'm trying to develop a function that identifies the missing values and this is what I have so far:

```py
def missing_values(var1, var2, var3):
    if var1 is None:
        return 'Missing var1 in data'
    if var2 is None:
        return 'Missing var2 in data'
    if var3 is None:
        return 'missing var3 value in data'
    else:
        return 'No missing values in data'

print(missing_values(df))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: missing_values1() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'var2' and 'var3'
```

I know this is because the function is trying to find the two other parameters. How do I get the function to recognize that the parameters are within the data set? Or is there generally a better way to write this function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find empty or NaN entry in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159189/find-empty-or-nan-entry-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use inbuilt function to find `None`. And also `" " != None`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'var1':  ['pero03930', 'pero03930', None],
        'var2': ['121324', '232434', ' '],
        'var3': [343, 937, 989],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])

print(df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)])
```

### output

```sh
   var1 var2  var3
2  None  nan   989
```

### Your Code

If you want, your code working then check following code. But your code has lots of problem.

- When first `None` found, it will return. It never find other `None` in same row

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'var1':  ['pero03930', 'pero03930', None],
        'var2': ['121324', '232434', ' '],
        'var3': [343, 937, 989],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])


def missing_values(var1,var2,var3):
    if var1 is None:
        return 'Missing var1 in data'
    if var2 is None:
        return 'Missing var2 in data'
    if var3 is None:
        return 'missing var3 value in data'
    else:
        return 'No missing values in data'

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(missing_values(row["var1"], row["var2"], row["var3"]))
```

### Output

```sh
No missing values in data
No missing values in data
Missing var1 in data
```

If this solution solves your problem then accept it else comment what's the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Can you explain why the code has lots of problems? It doesn't matter that once a null or None is found that it stops searching, I just need to know if there are 1 or more nulls. Using the way you have used the function here does work

Comment: If you don't care about other None when one found then your code is OK. If your problem is solved the please accept it.