# How to show blank values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe df has column `TX_order`, when I tried to sum null values `df.isnull().sum(axis=0)`
The output was `TX_order` has 0 null values, however it has blank values. How can I show it or calculate this blank values to can remove it.

As in example below the `TX_order` has blank values but doesn't appear in the output

df

| A header | TX_order |
| --- | --- |
| First |  |
| Second | row |
| Second |  |
| Second | row |
| Second |  |

Comment: Please show a sample of the DataFrame

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find empty or NaN entry in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159189/find-empty-or-nan-entry-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: It's not blank value, it's empty string.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, I don't understand your edit in my question , you wrote the same code of mine.

Comment: @asmaamahmoud, just to make sure, can you `print(df.sample(5).to_dict("list"))` ?

Comment: @Timeless, the output was 'Order_TX': ['', '', '', '', '']}, But when I tried df.replace("", None).isnull().sum(), the output still 0

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'Order_TX': ['', '', '', '', '']}).replace('', None).isnull().sum()` gives `Order_TX    5`, you should give a reproducible example that lead to the behaviour described.

Comment: My df has 2131283  rows some of them are ' ' and the remain with values as the example I explained

Comment: My edit is to improve the format of the column name and code, they should be enclosed by backtick to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have *empty strings*, try to [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) them before [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html)/[`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) :

```
df.replace("", None).isnull().sum() # `axis=0` by default
```

Output :

```
A header    0
TX_order    3
dtype: int64
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A header": ["First", "Second", "Second", "Second", "Second"],
     "TX_order": ["", "row", "", "row", ""]}
)
```